# core plot how to set background color for minor interval for specific row count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, core-plot

I am new to core plot.

**what i have ?**

1) Y axis with major interval of 50.  range ( 0 - 300)
    so my y axis starts from 0, 50, 100 ... 300. Fair Enough.

2)  Drawn major grid line.

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *yGridLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
yGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
yGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
y.majorGridLineStyle = yGridLineStyle;
```

Grid Line shows in white Color.

**What I need?**

1)  I want 3 different colors to show at the background of the graph.

2) From 0 to 65  -> Red Color.

3) From 65 - 88  -> Blue color.

4) Above 88 -> Green Color.

How can i achieve the same?.. Kindly Advice.

**What  i Tried?**

I tried with **alternatingBandFills** of y axis.  Example:

```
y.alternatingBandFills = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTColor redColor], [CPTColor greenColor], nil];
```

But it fills only based on the major interval. I could not able to mention specifically which minor interval it has to start with the range.

Comment: vertical coloring or horizontal..

Comment: ok then make line , set color and make with high width

Comment: Would you mind providing few snaps of the code?

Comment: are you able to draw line on graph ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Plot calls these "limit bands".

```
CPTPlotRange *bandRange;
CPTFill *bandFill;

// red
bandRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                         length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(65.0)];
bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];
[y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:bandRange
                                                      fill:bandFill]];

// blue
bandRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(65.0)
                                         length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(23.0)];
bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
[y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:bandRange
                                                      fill:bandFill]];

// green
bandRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(88.0)
                                         length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(212.0)];
bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
[y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:bandRange
                                                      fill:bandFill]];
```